# Encoding of entities - no perfect solution?

Tags: ckeditor, redmine

We use the ckeditor plugin for redmine (https://github.com/a-ono/redmine_ckeditor) and experience the following problem:

- if encoding of basicEntities / entities is set to false, xml/html text is not shown correctly when stored via the CKEditor (https://github.com/a-ono/redmine_ckeditor/issues/158), there also is a problem with pressing the show sourcecode button or editing content repeatedly
- if these parameters are not set, problems with quotes in code blocks (shown as &quot), links with parameters (& is incorrectly encoded) and wiki links with umlauts or other accentuated letters are broken (https://github.com/a-ono/redmine_ckeditor/issues/132)

As a-ono, the dev of the plugin, puts it: "There seems to be no perfect solution."

I found http://komlenic.com/246/encoding-entities-to-work-with-ckeditor-3/ , http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/inside-tries-create-paragraph#comment-54348 and some additional information about "forceSimpleAmpersand:true" as well as config.entities_latin = false;, but I'm not too sure how to proceed. We are in the process of moving additional users to Redmine, but it's quite a show-stopper if they are not able to post links or xml/html content (e.g. as part of an error report)

So this goes out to all CKEditor Pros. Any hints?

Comment: should be solved now. https://github.com/a-ono/redmine_ckeditor/issues/158

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say that but it looks like the plugin for Redmine is broken. CKEditor itself has nothing to do here - it can correctly read and write entities **if** data is loaded correctly. If some entities are decoded or encoded too much after saving them into database and loading them back it means that the backend is broken. Instead of touching CKEditor's options, which are totally fine by default, the backend should be fixed (meaning the plugin for Redmine or, less likely, Redmine itself).

Let's consider the following case. You want to write in your comment about an `<xml>` tag. The HTML for it will be:

```
<p>This is a tag: <code>&lt;xml&gt;</code>.</p>
```

And this is also what will be returned by `editor.getData()` or what's posted to the server if automatic integration with `<textarea>` is used.

Now, if you do (e.g. in the [demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo)):

```
editor.setData( '<p>This is a tag: <code>&lt;xml&gt;</code>.</p>' );
```

everything will be totally fine. The same content will be displayed:

[image: Loading data using editor.setData()]

However, many developers use the integration of CKEditor with `<textarea>`s and, unfortunately, they do not fully understand how it works. Let's load the exact data that was stored in a database into a textarea:

```
<textarea><p>This is a tag: <code>&lt;xml&gt;</code>.</p></textarea>
```

If you now try to read the value of this textarea from JavaScript using `textarea.value` you will get:

```
<p>This is a tag: <code><xml></code>.</p>
```

As you can see, the encoding of the `<xml>` tag was lost, because in HTML `&lt;` is read as `<`.

So what you need to do is to encode data once more before loading them to a textarea:

```
<textarea>&lt;p&gt;This is a tag: &lt;code&gt;&amp;lt;xml&amp;gt;&lt;/code&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
```

See now that all `<` characters become `&lt;`, but already encoded `&lt;` become `&amp;lt;`. This will assure that all the entities are correctly preserved when printing data to HTML. As you could see, it has nothing to do with CKEditor. And the same applies to displaying data created in CKEditor - the encoding must be preserved. If something is lost, it means that the backend encodes or decodes the data and it should not.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I hope we'll make some progress here.

Comment: I can't understand this: ```As you can see, the encoding of the <xml> tag was lost, because in HTML &lt; is read as <.```; why that would be interpreted as HTML, since isn't the [textarea supposed to contain just plain-text](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#elementdef-textarea). Why would the value be decoded as HTML entity? And, above all, what is performing that decoding? The browser Javascript implementation? Sorry for the maybe trivial question.

Answer (score 0):

We have a user who insists on putting in the python interpreter ">>>" in his python code blocks in a wiki.
These get converted to the HTML entities &gt;&gt;&gt; when saved to the wiki database. When viewed, these are not converted back to the ">>>" as it is inside a <pre> block.

I found that changing plugins/redmine_ckeditor/lib/redmine_ckeditor/wiki_formatting/formatter.rb line 17:

```
    %Q[<pre>\n<code class="#{lang} syntaxhl">#{
      Redmine::SyntaxHighlighting.highlight_by_language(code, lang)
    }</code>\n</pre>]
```

to

```
    %Q[<pre>\n<code class="#{lang} syntaxhl">#{
      Redmine::SyntaxHighlighting.highlight_by_language(CGI.unescapeHTML(code), lang)
    }</code>\n</pre>]
```

solved our problem with HTML entities in code.